# jQuery validation plugin is not working?

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am trying to use jquery-validation plugin. For that i included in my jsp:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

In my js file i did:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#getCircleTspForm').validate({ 
        rules: {
            xyz: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages :{

            xyz: {
                required: 'Enter name'
            }
        },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                return false; // for demo
            }
        });

    });
```

`xyz` is a textfiled in jsp.

```
<s:textfield name="xyz"></s:textfield>
```

But when i submit the form empty the error message is not displayed.
I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function $('#getCircleTspForm').validate({
```

Do i have to include some other file to make it work??

Is the code wrong??

Comment: have u got any console errors..??

Comment: @Outlooker      TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function

$('#getCircleTspForm').validate({

Comment: did you include the jquery validation plugin files

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I load this file:   <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: suggest you debug your js code, you can use chrome or firebug, from there, it easily notify you what error it is... you may also go to check whether you include the js lib successfully or not..

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the jquery plugin first and then the validate plugin mate..Plz try it out

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Anyways i have created a `fiddle` for u mate.

**Jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/ShZ6M/

Comment: Yeah i load first jquery then validate

Comment: No jQuery first. This is the Order:<script type="text/javascript"
 src="/common/jquery/external/js/jquery.min.js">
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="javascript/jquery-validate.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/additional-methods.js"></script>

Comment: I have updated my answer.there is a possibility that the path you have referenced the script may not be correct mate..Please do cross check it.